# Using OData (server side) with Mono

Tags: .net, mono, odata

We have pure OData service (.Net 4, hosted in IIS) which works fine. We want to deploy this service on Linux.

Is it possible to use OData with Mono? Have anyone had such experience?

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to use odata for our project, but i seems that they don't support odata.
Under http://www.mono-project.com/WCF_Development you will find the entry "Data Services". under not supported

*Components with no plan to support*

- WorkflowServices. we have no plan to work on WF3. There are WF4-based
  WCF stuff in System.ServiceModel, which is in different story (though
  no plan for this either).
- RIA Services. Basically there are Silverlight SDK assemblies that are
  to be embedded in the app, so we don't have to bother much.
- WSHttpBinding and its dependencies
- Federation (I'm not sure what it is supposed to do.)
- Silverlight PollingDuplex binding element.
- WSDualHttpBinding (post-WSHttpBinding work)
- MSMQ stack: Msmq bindings and MsmqIntegration.
- **Data Services.**
- Net peer channel improvements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Owin Self Host with HttpListener on mono. Then host your asp.net web api odata 4 app on top of that. Works like a charm (-:

But, be careful about following issue:
https://github.com/odata/odata.net/issues/165